# difference between remove & del in Python's List

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the difference between remove and del ?
I read that remove deletes the first occurrence, while del removes the item at a specified index, but I tried to use index with remove and it worked so, what's the actual difference and the actual use???

```
>>> list=[1,2,3,4]
... list.remove(list[0])
... print(list)
[2, 3, 4]
>>> list=[1,2,3,4]
... list.remove(1)
... print(list)
[2, 3, 4]
>>> list=[1,2,3,4]
... del(list[0])
... print(list)
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: In this case there will *be no difference*, since the items in the list are unique. Of course, if you don't know the index, `.remove` will be more useful. But try it with `l = [1,2,3,4,1]` and `l.remove(l[4])` and `del l[4]`

Comment: that helped me, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete particular element whose index is unknown from the list use remove(element) and if you want to delete element at particular index use del(list[index]).

Answer (score 0):

remove removes the first matching value

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,2]
```

l.remove() will remove first occurance and modified list will be

```
[1,3,4,5,6,2]
```

but using  del you can del last last as well

```
del l[-1]
```

I found more useful when want to remove multiple value:

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

now i want to remove from index 2 to 4

```
del l[2:5]
#[1, 2, 6, 7]
```